# What function yields the semi-minor axis of an ellipse on the chord of one circle and at a known distance from the intersection of 2 related circles?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I'm trying to avoid a clash during a parametric design for 3D printing that involves the intersection of multiple shapes. The design can be simplified to consider only surfaces and then simplified further to consider a single plane, reducing the clash avoidance issue to a 2D problem. That's the problem I'm writing about here.

Two concentric circles with radii *R* and *R*–*s* intersect with an ellipse in a particular way. The vertices of the ellipse are on the circle with radius *R* at points **A** and **B**, creating chord AB with length equal to the ellipse major axis 2*a* where *a*<*R*. A third circle of radius *r* with *s*<*r*<*a* is centered at point **A**. This circle intersects the circle with radius *R*–*s* at two points **C1** and **C2**. Call the point closer to the ellipse **C1**. The semi-minor axis of the ellipse, *b*, is chosen such that **C1** remains outside the ellipse at a distance of *t* from the ellipse. What is the function *b(a, r, R, s, t)*?

Other parameters in the design define particular values for *r*, *s*, and *t*. The locations of the center of the concentric circles and of the points **A** and **B** are also defined, thereby defining *R* and *a* and the location of points **C1** and **C2**. I also know—as previously stated—that 0<*s*<*r*<*a*<*R*, and I also know that 0<*t*<*r*. The value of *t* may be less than, equal to, or greater than *s*.

The free parameter is *b*, the semi-minor axis of the ellipse. The clash is avoided when *b* is sufficiently close to zero to create an ellipse that remains a distance *t* or greater from **C1**. However, a value of *b* that is too small results in a 3D shape that is aesthetically unpleasant for other reasons. I can tell by visual inspection that a particular value of *b* is required to have an ellipse that is a distance *t* from **C1** when *a*, *r*, *R*, *s*, and *t* are known, but having the function to describe the relationship would be very useful. I rarely deal with problems at this level of intricacy, and I'm getting a bit stuck. Any help would be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given data fix the positions of points $A$, $B$ and $C_1$, which I'll rename $C$ for the sake of brevity. Set up then a coordinate system where the coordinates of those points are:
$$
A=(-a,0),\quad B=(a,0),\quad C=(x_C,y_C).
$$
The equation of the ellipse can then be written as:
$$
{x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}=1,
\tag1
$$
where $b$ is to be found.
If $P=(x,y)$ is the point on the ellipse nearest to $C$, then we have another equation:
$$
a^2(x-x_C)y=b^2(y-y_C)x.
\tag 2
$$
Finally, we also require $CP=t$, leading to a third equation:
$$
(x-x_C)^2+(y-y_C)^2=t^2.
\tag3
$$
By solving the above system of three equations one can find the unknowns $x$, $y$ and $b$. But it's a system of sixth degree (at least), so I don't expect an explicit solution to exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was using a poor choice for the origin. With your help, I found an explicit solution. I used the transformed variables x' = x - xc and y' = y - yc , solved your equation 2 for b^2, and substituted that expression into the b^2 in your equation 1 along with the solution for y' from your equation 3. This results in like terms of the sixth degree cancelling, yielding a quartic equation for x' that has a somewhat intricate explicit solution. That value can be used to generate y' and b. I'm unsure whether to do all that by code, but that's not a math question.